# Что такое "подгруппа языков" и чем она отличается от "группы"?

Tags: лингвистика

Прочёл дифирамбы, посвящённые одному идиотскому, но лелеющему национальный слух (нацию, простите, не буду называть - стыжусь за своих), труду. Ко всему прочему там увидел такое предложение:

> **Успешная дешифровка надписей на фестском диске оживила почти забитый и
> давно отброшенный в неизвестность
> догреческий пелазгский язык,
> родственный лезгинской подгруппе
> кавказских языков.**

Кто сможет внести ясность что такое "**подгруппа языков**"? Чем она отличается от **"группы"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить нечего, Ниманд прав. Приведу лишь ссылку,там все подробно и доступно написано про группы, подгруппы и семьи.[Лингвистика](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=622.z7OW7NehHynZ4S0YUJUnH-D-1GBcs9SOQFpAbk0fyAwBbsnIXezhamCXXoq5kZmLQ9l_5x1sxVNFDHB6rirsDA.732590de75ad94722751817b575534f12b7099fc&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xti-b8lArfpY2fz6fP4kJz3523BIyRaKdBrJ-E3tDYkBsavJGHcvy-fZ3mW3WhMdwxgbkoT2Y1MCNHRHI7XYWrX_dDhkbfra-RJiYG84NBiW_Tl3U3TnJBGaF4YvQbHD45vcTrrpjOmQuQ434xk4I-uGm0zmPej7sO3OrvjmYoEHqUFe9_S2mm8WkjTHv8wzriAAgpfon3gDR6FdA_DcR1Rwi52py1FnozhkvmR-wUd5A&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbXhDbFZScnpoZ29nZ0RNaGZxQkVIaGdIbzRHeVBvb0xwei1wYTRRWmkyQU5LSzl3WU91bFVOMDBvX0t4c3VtbFNzZFUwOWZjRXotc1FpbmdVM2JVZHc2c05UeDZDMTZ6anlzOERBNWo5WEZ0cGRvZ0F5eHhqM1ZrUHo3WXM2aUkwdmZDLUlSRDJZXzU1aU10YmZtUTUwYXlIc0k2OVJaeDhyWF9vMUZSSFRK&b64e=2&sign=5b0d2c0eac7319370714edc2d9d1017a&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O6O6JuCtJj2AAoLTQXwvewA4EO4K4lAq7cj8Enj-j0TNw&l10n=ru&cts=1425932025077&mc=3.373557262275185)

Comment: Уважаемый Серж! Ваша ссылка содержит в себе более исчерпывающий и обоснованный ответ, из которого следует, что скорее группа и ветвь идентичные понятия, а не группа и подгруппа:

"**Объединяя языки на основе родственных связей, генеалогическая классификация выделяет такие группы, как семья, ветвь (группа), подгруппа. ... Большие семьи распадаются на ветви (группы), объединяющие более близкие по родству языки, ветви в свою очередь могут быть представлены несколькими подгруппами.**"

При всём своём уважении к пользователю "Niemand" я не могу отдать предпочтение его ответу перед Вашим. Спс. Зачё

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно внутри славянской группы языков выделить восточную, западную и южную подгруппу. А иногда говорят о восточной, западной и южной группе славянских языков. Или о восточнославянских, западнославянских и южнославянских языках славянской группы.

То есть абсолютно четких различий-то нет.

Хренотень вами процитированных "трудов" не в этом. )))

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Подожду ещё денёк, а то и второй, и, если не будет других вариантов, то приму Ваш ответ.
Что касается "хренотени", то я знаю, что он заключён в том, что **Фестский диск, якобы, успешно дешифрован**